# Adjust Height Minipage and Tikz Pic

Tags: minipage, alignment

I am working within the same document and I am having difficulty moving my picture. Ideally, I would like it lower and more aligned with the table (see image).  I tried adjusting the minipages, and also the tikzpicture but I am only able to lower it by a fraction.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{multicol,fancyhdr,fullpage,setspace,parskip,float}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


% HEADER AND FOOTER
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus BC}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{\textbf{Skill Builder: Topics 2.1-2.3 -  The Definition of the Derivative}}
\chead{\textbf{}}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{Mr. Bennett}
\cfoot{Flint Hill Upper School}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1.5em


\begin{document}

For Problems 9 and 10, consider the sketch of the function, \(f\left(x\right)\), to the right. 


    
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.8\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            9. a). Find \(f\left(1\right)\) and \(f\left(4\right)\). &  b). Calculate \(f\left(4\right)-f\left(1\right)\). \\[1in] \hline   
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}   
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=.5}]
            \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,thick]
                \addplot[thick,red,samples=1000,smooth,domain=-1:5]{x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please remove all lines, not needed here, like packages, definitions etc. Thank you

Comment: Just cleaned it up some. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way:

- replace the second `minipage` by a `raisebox` (neg raise=lowerbox)
- avoid an empty line between `end of first minipage` and `raisebox`
- with a blank line the `Tikz picture` coincides with the table etc.

Relevant part:

```
    ...
    \end{minipage}   
    \raisebox{-13mm}{% <<< new
        \begin{tikzpicture} ...
```

Hint: I added some extra text, just to verify, the layout behaves as I assumed.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{multicol,fancyhdr,fullpage,setspace,parskip,float}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


% HEADER AND FOOTER
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus BC}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{\textbf{Skill Builder: Topics 2.1-2.3 -  The Definition of the Derivative}}
\chead{\textbf{}}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{Mr. Bennett}
\cfoot{Flint Hill Upper School}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1.5em


\begin{document}

For Problems 9 and 10, consider the sketch of the function, \(f\left(x\right)\), to the right. 
For Problems 9 and 10, consider the 
\bigskip
 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            9. a). Find \(f\left(1\right)\) and \(f\left(4\right)\). &  b). Calculate \(f\left(4\right)-f\left(1\right)\). \\[1in] \hline   
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}   
    \raisebox{-13mm}{% <<< new
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=.5}]
            \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,thick]
                \addplot[thick,red,samples=1000,smooth,domain=-1:5]{x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

Some more text to follow.

\end{document}
```